# How to change className dynamically with more than one ternary involved?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a star component who display the selected stars in yellow with the '.star-selected' css class and grey with the '.star-unselected' one. and a selected bool initialised to false. This part is working fine.

what i can't achieve is the same but with hovers, i mean if i hover the third star, i want the 3 first stars in yellow, and in my mouse leave those uneselected get back to grey if they was hovered and those selected remains yellow.

As i change the star's classes with the selected bool, i tried the same with hovered bool in star component and usage of useState, as it is for the [starsSelected, selectStar]

part of StarRating.jsx

```
const StarRating = (props) => {

    const [starsSelected, selectStar] = useState( 0 );
    const [starsHovered, selectHover] = useState( 0 );
    const totalStars = props.nbStar;

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{ props.title }</h1>
            <div className="star-rating">

            {[...Array(totalStars)].map((starItem, i) => (
                <Star
                key={i}
                id={i}
                selected={i < starsSelected}
                hovered={i < starsHovered}
                onClick={() => {
                    selectStar(i + 1);
                }}
                onMouseEnter={() => {
                    selectHover(i + 1);
                    {/* selectStar(starsHovered); */}
                }}
                onMouseLeave={() => {
                    selectHover(0);
                    {/* selectStar(starsSelected); */}
                }}
                />
            ))}
```

Part of Star.jsx

```
const Star = ({ 
    hovered = false, 
    selected = false, 
    onClick = f => f, 
    onMouseEnter = f => f,
    onMouseLeave = f => f
}) => 
    (
    <div  
    className={       
        selected
        ? 'star-selected star'
        : 'star-unselected star'
    } 
    onClick={ onClick }
    onMouseEnter={ onMouseEnter } 
    onMouseLeave={ onMouseLeave } 
    />
    );
```

I'm not sure if i have a chance to solve my problem this way, somone could explain me what i've missed or lead me to the beggining of a new approach ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put also `selected || hovered` into className, this way "start-selected" css class **will apply only if the start is selected and not hovered**

Also change StarRating.jsx like below to make it not hovered after click

```js
const StarRating = (props) => {
...
       <Star
         ...
         onClick={() => {
           selectStar(i + 1);
           selectHover(0);
         }}
         ...
       />
))}
```

Comment: it solved my problem, it was ' selected || hovered ' instead of && thank you !